# Files saving to OneDrive instead of PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, onedrive

I recently uninstalled OneDrive because of the issues I was having with it and now whenever I save a file it goes to OneDrive instead of my PC. I can see the file on my desktop but when I check its location, it shows up as C:\Users*user*\OneDrive\Desktop instead of C:\Users*user*\Desktop. I would like to save it to my PC (hard drive) without OneDrive interfering in any way.

*Other* I have checked the storage in system settings and PC is the only place it can save files which is even more absurd, I unchecked autosave to OneDrive before I uninstalled it as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a side-effect of OneDrive's folder protection feature. It has moved the location of your Desktop into the OneDrive folder. If OneDrive is not running, then it isn't able to upload the documents, so **they remain only on your computer**. [This](https://superuser.com/a/1358268/911683) answer goes into more detail.

The simplest way to revert the location of your Desktop is to:

1. Open Windows Explorer (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>)
2. Right click the *Desktop* folder under *This PC*
3. Click *Properties*
4. Click the *Location* tab
5. Click *Restore Default*
6. Click *OK*

[image: Desktop folder properties]