# Onedrive Desktop Problems

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I bought a new Windows 10 device. My desktop currently displays items from `username/onedrive/desktop`

How do I change it so my desktop displays items from 
`username/desktop`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Files saving to OneDrive instead of PC](https://superuser.com/questions/1378912/files-saving-to-onedrive-instead-of-pc)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the AutoProtection feature in OneDrive that is not very well explained by Microsoft. Instead of keeping a local copy of your files, it moves all of the local folders to the OneDrive folder, and creates symlinks (that don't always work) in place of local content.
To disable, go to OneDrive settings - Auto-save - choose folders to unprotect.
You will then have to manually move the files/folders from OneDrive to the actual local place (so OneDrive/Desktop will need to be moved to %userfolder%/Desktop to restore local access)
Also see this [this](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913522-onedrive-on-windows/suggestions/36053329-warn-users-about-folders-being-moved-when-protect)